# iOS:WCSession.sendMessageData failed on simulator when I send data from iPhone to iWatch

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I'm trying to send text and image from iPhone to iWatch using WCSession.sendMessageData and application crashed on iPhone simulator with not any error/exception. When I just send text with WCSession.sendMessage all work fine.

I uploaded code to GitHub: https://github.com/P-A-R-U-S/iPhoneToIWatch

Comment: You are sending `NSString` object instead of `NSData` in that message, that's why it is not communicating properly. Convert it to `NSData` and send that data object.

Comment: I'm sending a NSObject which contains 2 properties:  `class Message: NSData  {
    var Text: NSString?
    var Image: UIImage?
}` - shall I inherit from NSData and all other properties will also has NSData type or just Text property ?

Comment: Not really, You should subclass from `NSObject` not from `NSData`. Point is , that you can not send an object of any custom class directly to WatchApp. First you need to convert it to NSData using `NSKeyedArchive` API and then at WatchApp side convert it back to the custom object.